# Retrieve data from database in OpenLayers GIS

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, google-maps, vector

I am using this code but it shows nothing, what's wrong with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en'> 
<?php
   $conn_string = "host=localhost  dbname=postgis_21 user=postgres      password=1234";
   $dbconn4 = pg_connect($conn_string);
   //$result = pg_exec(); 
  $rs = pg_query("select ST_AsText(geom) from pak_adm2_pco_20110324");
  $row = pg_fetch_array($rs, 0, PGSQL_NUM);
  print_r($row[0]);
   ?>
<head> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
<?php /*<script
src="http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.0&appid=euzuroopenlayers"></script>
<script
src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.
ashx?v=6.2&mkt=en-us"></script> */?>
<script type='text/javascript'>

var map;

function init() {

        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element',{
        //projection: 'EPSG:900913',
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508,
        20037508, 20037508.34),
        maxResolution: 156543.0339,
        units: 'm'
    });

    //Create a base layer
    var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'WMS Layer Title',
        'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
        {layers: 'basic'},
        {}
    );
    var wms_layer_labels = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
     'Location Labels',
     'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
     {layers: 'clabel,ctylabel,statelabel',
     transparent: true},
     {opacity: .5}
    );

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    var vector_layer = new   OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('More Advanced Vector Layer');

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()); 
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()); 
    parser = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(); 
    var vector_layer1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Basic Vector Layer');
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-72, 42);
    var feature_point = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);
    vector_layer.addFeatures([feature_point]);
    map.addLayers([wms_layer, vector_layer1, vector_layer,wms_layer_labels]);

     <?php if(isset($row))
    {
      while($row = pg_fetch_array($row, 0, PGSQL_BOTH)){?>
        var wkt = "<?php echo $data['geom'];?>"; 
        var geometry = parser.read(wkt);
        geometry.geometry.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
        vector_layer.addFeatures([geometry]); 
    <?php } } ?>

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(vector_layer));
    if(!map.getCenter()){
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='init();'>
<div id='map_element' style='width: 1000px; height: 800px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot edit your question to make it readable, can you please edit the post so that the code is formatted correctly. You do that by putting 4 spaces in front of each line. Check the formatting options available [here!](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Secondly, please state what you are actually trying to achieve with the code; ie: what is it supposed to do!

Answer (score 1):

It appears hat you are trying to display features from a database on the map and are sending the results of a database Query in the html delivered to a client.

OpenLayers does not work that way. To achieve what you want to do, you have to create the map and then load the features via an Ajax Call from the browser back to your server that then queries the database, the flow looks like this:

```
Create Map Client Side --> 
Browser Displays the Map --> 
OpenLayers requests data from Server via AJAX --> 
Server queries the database --> 
Server formats data as KML, GeoJson or similar --> 
Sever responds to AJAX call with requested data -->
OpenLayers Vector Layer Displays the data
```

There is more information on OpenLayers Vector Layers [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html), and the code to retrieve  and display the data as KML and display on the Vector Layer would look something like this:

```
                var vectorlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
                            "MyLayer", 
                            {
                                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                                styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(styletouse),
                                projection: wgs84,
                                attribution: attribution,

                                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP
                                ({
                                    url: "http://ajax.mydomain.com",
                                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML
                                            ({
                                            //  extractStyles: true, 
                                            //  extractTracks: true,
                                                extractAttributes: true,
                                                maxDepth: 2
                                            }),

                                }),
                                visibility: true
                            });


                map.addLayers([vectorlayer]);
```

You would have to write your PHP script to retrieve the data and format it as KML, and it would live, in this example, at `http://ajax.mydomain.com`

TO do this as a step by step and see how it works, do the following:

- Just get the map layers to display without trying to get the data, by removing the all the PHP from your code.
- When you have the Map Displaying correctly, then add the code to retrieve the data you want to display.